# Debug log is not working for FixedUpdate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Debug.log works fine in `Awake()` function but not in `FixedUpdate()`. Not sure what is wrong

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SteamVR_TrackedObject))]
public class PickupParent : MonoBehaviour {

    SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;

    void Awake () {
        trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
        Debug.Log("debug log is working");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdated () {
        SteamVR_Controller.Device device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);

        if (device.GetTouch(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("You are holding down the 'Touch' on the Trigger");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you added an extra `d` to the function name `FixedUpdated` should be `FixedUpdate`.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdated () { // <---------- should be FixedUpdate
    ...
```

Also the first thing I would have tried is added a `Debug.Log` call at the start of  `FixedUpdate` to see if the function was being called at all. It not being called would have indicated an issue with the function. If it was called then it would have pointed to the if statement wrapped around the log call.